# Can't install packages globally on Windows using npm

Tags: node.js, npm

When I try to install a package globally using `npm`, it complaints about not being able to create some files. How can I solve this issue? **I am on Windows 10**

[image]

Comment: You're trying to write to program files, so you must run as administrator.

Comment: @Rob Sorry for that, I'll keep that in mind from the next time

Comment: @Alejandro But `yarn` and `pnpm` work. Only `npm` does not work. And it didn't cause this problem sometime ago.. Also, running as admin everytime is not efficient imo

Comment: No idea what `yarn` and `pnpm` do internally, but clearly `npm` is trying to write to read-only folders (program files) as stated in the error message. Maybe before you've got node installed outside program files? This is the exact same reason why Linux users need to put `sudo` in front of many commands, precisely to gain admin rights. You need to do the same every time you manipulate global libraries (which should be very few instances).

Comment: How about fixing it this time?

Comment: @Alejandro Yes I know how `sudo` is put in unix terminals but I am on Windows. Do you think I should make an issue on the `npm` github? Because that's the only way to reach there.. Also, `yarn` does the same process i think. But `pnpm` works differently

Comment: @MaxProgramming No idea where `yarn` or `pnpm` saves the global libraries, but should they be installed to program files, it would raise the very same problem. This problem definitely isn't a bug in `npm`, so no need to open a ticket to them. The error message clearly points to the root cause, and the solution is just to elevate. There is nothing `npm` can do to bypass OS permissions.

Answer (score 3):

As the error suggests, you might not have the appropriate permissions. Therefore, try to launch the cmd as an administrator, and then run your command.

Comment: check this out too https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc771525(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: Yes, it works when I launch it as admin (using PowerShell btw).  But why would I launch everytime as admin?

Comment: It didn't cause this problem sometime ago. I am facing this from a couple of months and I had to use `yarn` and `pnpm` for global installation.. I even reinstalled nodejs but that didn't solve the issue.

I think it needs admin privileges but it's not efficient to launch it as admin every single time I want to install a package globally

Comment: i think it has to do with windows user permission. Check and confirm that the currently signed in user is an administrator and not a guest or standard user. That should fix it going forward

Comment: i would like an upvote if my ideas worked

Comment: The currently signed-in user is an admin. But still, this problem persists

Comment: @MaxProgramming UAC makes sure that you don't get admin privileges until you explicitly use "run as administrator". The error message clearly says that you don't have write access to the program files folder.

Comment: @Alejandro Yes but it didn't cause the issue some time ago. And whenever I see anyone's YouTube video installing a global package on Windows, it just works fine ‍♂️

Comment: @MaxProgramming No idea what was your setup some time ago, but no doubt something changed, most likely replaced a portable install with a real install into program files. Remember that "global" really means to save libraries to the node.exe folder, which is of course subject to the very same OS permissions check as the rest of the system. Saving to a portable install in your desktop requires no more access than your normal user, but saving to program files requires admin, as any other system-wide install.